# como encontrar repetidos en un array javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Hola Amigos dado un array:

```
var x = [1,9,2,1,5,6,2,9];
```

Como podría identificar los elementos que se repiten en el array x y poner esos repetidos en otro array ?

se que debo recorrerlo con un `for (i=0; i<x.length;i++)` y guardarlos en otro array con un push, pero no sabría como comparar cada elemento con todos los elementos del array.

agradezco sugerencias. soy principiante en Javascript.

gracias por sus aportes

Answer (score 7):

Si por sacar te refieres a eliminarlos:

```js
var x = [1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,7]
var uniqs = x.filter(function(item, index, array) {
  return array.indexOf(item) === index;
})
console.log(uniqs); // [ 1, 2, 5, 6 ]
```

filter ignora los elementos que regresen un falso, por lo tanto si cuando preguntas en que posición se encuentra un item y no corresponde con el index que tiene en el array actual significa que es repetido.

Comment: sería genial si a tu respuesta añades el por que del uso de xs, es decir que identifica y el por que de indexof

Comment: Hola gracias por tu aporte. no me refiero a elminarlos, me refiero a sacarlos del array x y poner los repetidos en un array z por ejemplo. gracias

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que deseas el obtener los elementos que se repite de un array puede intentar lo siguiente:

```js
var elementos = [1,1,3,5,6,4,9,5,3,5,7,9,0,1];
var repetidos = [];
var temporal = [];

elementos.forEach((value,index)=>{
  temporal = Object.assign([],elementos); //Copiado de elemento
  temporal.splice(index,1); //Se elimina el elemnto q se compara
  /**
   * Se busca en temporal el elemento, y en repetido para 
   * ver si esta ingresado al array. indexOf returna
   * -1 si el elemento no se encuetra
   **/
  if(temporal.indexOf(value)!=-1 && repetidos.indexOf(value)==-1)      repetidos.push(value);
});

console.log(repetidos);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hola puedes utilizar el un [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set) para remover elementos repetidos y después obtener un Array así: `[...unicos]`

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,5,5];

let unicos = new Set(arr);

console.log("Unicos: ", [...unicos]);
```

El *set* preserva los elementos en orden de inserción y puded ser iterado de la siguiente manera:

```
for (let item of mySet) console.log(item);
```