# ¿Cómo obtener el número de elementos repetidos en un array JS?

Tags: javascript, array, arraylist, position

Necesito saber la cantidad de elementos que se repiten dentro del array, por ejemplo 3 unos, 3 dos, etc. Ahora con **index of** solo obtengo la posición del primer elemento, 3 para el caso de este ejemplo, pero necesito la cantidad de repetidos.

¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

```
  var numbers = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8];

  console.log(numbers.indexOf(3));
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: La respuesta la puedes encontrar en este post: [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168678/como-encontrar-repetidos-en-un-array-javascript)

Comment: pues es no quiero eliminarlos si no saber cuantas veces se repite un elemento dentro del array

Comment: Checa esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/116252/contar-numeros-repetidos-en-un-array/307472#307472

Answer (score 2):

Checa el siguiente código:

```js
const numbers = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8];
const specimens = numbers.filter((number, i) => i == 0 ? true : numbers[i - 1] != number);
const counterSpecimens = specimens.map(spec => {
    return {number: spec, count: 0};
});

counterSpecimens.map((countSpec, i) =>{
    const actualSpecLength = numbers.filter(number => number === countSpec.number).length;
    countSpec.count = actualSpecLength;
})

console.log(counterSpecimens);
```

Lo que hacemos es

- crear un listado de los números que contiene el arreglo sin repetirse
- luego a partir de éste creamos un objeto que contendrá el numero y a su vez la cantidad de veces que se repite iniciando en cero
- por ultimo con un map y dentro de este un filter:

---

```
counterSpecimens.map((countSpec, i) =>{
    const actualSpecLength = numbers.filter(number => number === countSpec.number).length;
    countSpec.count = actualSpecLength;
})
```

Buscamos cuantas veces se repite nuestro numero y se lo asignamos a la propiedad count de nuestro objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí otras forma de hacerlo.

```
[...new Set([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8])]
```

```
Array.from(new Set([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8]));
```

```
let numbers = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8];

numbers.filter((item, index) => numbers.indexOf(item) === index)
```

```
let numbers = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8];
numbers.reduce((unique, item) => unique.includes(item) ? unique : [...unique, item], [])
```

Extraje estos ejemplos de [aquí](https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-remove-array-duplicates-in-es6-5daa8789641c)

Answer (score 0):

```
var repeated = numbers.reduce((counter, value) => {if(!counter[value]) counter[value] = 1; else counter[value]++; return counter}, []);

repeated.forEach((replays,number) => console.log(number, '=>', replays));
```

Si en lugar de tener un array de enteros, es otro tipo de objeto debes hace lo siguiente:

```
var repeated = ["uno", "dos","tres","dos","seis","tres"].reduce((counter, value) => {if(!counter[value]) counter[value] = 1; else counter[value]++; return counter}, []);

Object.entries(repeated).forEach(counter => console.log(counter[0], ' => ', counter[1]))
```